# Dynamically allocate and free up cores for DPDK application

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, linux-kernel, dpdk

I have a dpdk application running and I have a **HandlePackets()** single core function which can run in a single core and handle up to **10000 packets per second**. now lets say I simply started the dpdk app by this "**./my_dpdk_app -l 5**" so the main thread will be binded to core 5, now depending on the number of incoming packets I want to **allocate new cores, run the HandlePacket() function to that cores and forward the traffics**. and when traffic goes low I also want to **free up the cores unnecessarily running HandlePackets() function** so that non dpdk processes can use it (as far I know, if dpdk reserves a core and even use less than 100% of it, no other non dpdk processes can use that, correct me if I am wrong..!).

is this dynamic allocating & free up cores to dpdk even possible? and if so then how or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You want to set/reset thread affinity maybe. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html#:~:text=DESCRIPTION%20top,to%20one%20of%20those%20CPUs.

Comment: I already checked the affinity things but it is on OS level and it seems like it can fail seriously.  I expected to have something from dpdk as they should have some mechanism to handle these kinda scenario, right? otherwise for large possible incoming packets in some times I can't expect to waste so many cpu cores by running all the time and doing nothing which could be used by non-dpdk processes?

Comment: Fail seriously? What do you mean? Do you mean failure to make one thread run on a core?

Comment: I meant, as being an OS level command it would go wrong anytime for any mis-handling corner case by me while implementing and I saw that many advised to use that very carefully

Comment: So you would trust some third-party wrapper which in turn uses OS-level calls rather than using it yourself? What if that third-party wrapper misses handling a corner case?

Comment: I trust dpdk api's/handling more than being implemented by me as the programmers of this are the finest, thats why i would prefer their function over me trying to implement some OS handling manually. but maybe I have to do the affinity thing anyway if dpdk has no workaround it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. If I use a multiprocess client-server model for DPDK where the DPDK application is divided into 2 types of processes :

1. primary process
2. secondary processes

and every process runs and allocates core separately.

Here, the primary process (server) initializes all the memory pool, port, buffer, rte_ring, and whatever is needed and then starts polling from NIC. Then route them to RTE_RING's.

and, the secondary processes actually poll from the RTE_RINGs after discovery and do the processing. I also can pass the stats through IPC (inter-process communication) channel to the server process thus saving the printing thread too on the client side.

now, as I already can know at run time (by packet count per second) whether I am actually needing (and routing to) RTE_RINGs or not, I can simply not start the secondary processes or start them whenever necessary (load increases) and then stop them when the load reduces, thus saving the CPU usage when possible. Maybe I will have to write a bash program too, whose work will only be to run and stop client processes whenever necessary depending on the incoming packet per second.

** another way could be simply run dpdk application without the "-l" option (which I just figured out) to explicitly allocate cores for dpdk in the start of the application rather allocate cores only when needed and free them when needed. Then I could simply run **rte_eal_remote_launch()** (for allocating new core) for desired core but before calling that we must handle to release that core from any work it was doing by calling **rte_eal_wait_lcore()** (to free up cores) first. Checkout dpdk API sections for the detailed usages

I actually modified and ran a DPDK app with a client_server model but I didn't realize that it can help me this way.

Correct me if I am wrong as I am very new to DPDK and still learning